How do I await a Timer coroutine that necessitates being async in discord.py?
I'm trying to create a simple bot that can echo a message you send in your DMs after a certain amount of time. Following is the command and the function it calls within the Timer:
@bot.command()
async def reminder(ctx: commands.Context, message: str) -> None:
    print("scheduling reminder")
    event = {
        "message": message,
        "timer": Timer(5.0, send_rem, args=[ctx.author, message])
    }

    user_events[str(ctx.author.id)] = event
    event["timer"].start()
    print("scheduling reminder")

async def send_rem(author, message):
    print("sending reminder")
    DM_CHNL = await author.create_dm() if (author.dm_channel is None) else author.dm_channel
    if DM_CHNL != None:
        await DM_CHNL.send(message)

However, when I run the bot and use the reminder command, I get this error after the timer expires:
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\threading.py:1342: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'send_rem' was never awaited
  self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

I'm assuming the issue is because the send_rem function is async, but I can't stop it from being so because creating and sending messages are both asynchronous, and I can't figure out how I'm meant to use asyncio, if at all, to handle this. I tried supplying asyncio.run as a callback for the timer ("timer": Timer(10.0, asyncio.run, args=[send_rem, [ctx.author, message]])) but it seems like Python won't let me specify args for a function within a function. How should I handle this?

What is the Timer class? It's probably a synchronous solution for waiting a certain amount of time. You should use await asyncio.sleep(seconds) if you want to wait a certain amount of time asynchronously.

Timer is a subclass of threading that creates a thread which waits for some time then runs a function. I'd love to use await sleep, but I also need to be able to cancel the task if needed. Furthermore, if I ever want to use slash commands, I can't allow the command itself to run for more than 3 minutes.

Using threads in combination with asyncio is always tricky and should be avoided. Your demand for creating cancelable alerts can be perfectly met using Coroutines and Tasks from asyncio.
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


@bot.command()
async def reminder(ctx: commands.Context, message: str) -> None:
    print("scheduling reminder")

    # we create a coroutine and don't use await
    # this way the coroutine will not be inserted into the event loop
    # and will not be executed
    coro = send_rem(ctx.author, message, 5)

    # let's insert the coroutine into the event loop
    # and get a task object that can be canceled using `task.cancel()`
    # it will run in the background
    task = asyncio.create_task(coro)

    event = {"message": message, "task": task}
    user_events[str(ctx.author.id)] = event

    await ctx.reply("Your reminder has been created.")


async def send_rem(author: discord.User, message: str, wait_seconds: float):

    # wait asynchronously (does not block the loop) until the reminder time
    await asyncio.sleep(wait_seconds)
    
    print("sending reminder")
    dm_channel = author.dm_channel or await author.create_dm()
    await dm_channel.send(message)

